# How to convert JOptionPane.showInputDialog to int to use in programme?

Tags: java, processing, joptionpane

So basically have an Array and am using the Joption input system so the user has to input a int between 1 and 3. Basically how do I use this int I to divide the number of objects in my array? Also not necessary but it would help if you could advise me how do I stop people inputting a number less than 1 and greater than 5.

```
       Rain[] drops = new Rain [3000]; // WANT TO DIVIDE INT INTO ARRAY
       import javax.swing.*;

       void setup() {
       noCursor();
       JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Please enter a number between one and three","2");
       }
```

So can I use the output from this to adjust the number of objects created by my array ?

Comment: well why don't you use a while loop and think about a test for a method, a boolean method that would only let a user input a number between one and five, then put that number they input into an int or a double, whichever you need, and another method that can return an array/int/double and accepts your int/double and divide the numbers in your array by it/ the length of the array I'm confused as to which you needed, its unclear

Answer (score 1):

Java cannot convert between strings and number by itself, you have to use specific functions, just use:

```
int ans = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...))
```

For your other question you may wanna do something like the following:

```
boolean inputAccepted = false;
while(!inputAccepted) {
  try {
    int answer = Integer.parseInt(JOption....

    // do some other validation checks
    if (answer < 1 || answer > 3) {
      // tell them it's still a bad number
    } else {
      //  a good value
      inputAccepted = true;
    }
  } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    // input is bad. popup something
    //  some communication
    // saying what you expect the user to enter.
  }

  ... do stuff with good input value
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged this with [processing](/questions/tagged/processing), I'll assume you're using the Processing language.

Processing has an [`int()`](https://www.processing.org/reference/intconvert_.html) function that converts from a `String` to an `int`.

```
float f = 65.0;
int i = int(f);
println(f + " : " + i);  // Prints "65.0 : 65"

char c = 'E';
i = int(c);
println(c + " : " + i);  // Prints "E : 69"
```

More info on this and related functions can be found in [the Processing reference](https://www.processing.org/reference/).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
String ans_s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Please enter a number between one and three","2");
int ans = Integer.parseInt(ans_s);
```

Please wrap this in try{ }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){}

Comment: Eh so i figured out I could use     Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog to turn it into an int. Next question is how do I divide this into the array I have ?